# Ansible - passing dynamic variables into Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm having a problem accessing dynamically named Ansible variables in a Jinja2 template. I have a list of tenants like this:

```
tenants:
  - liamtest1
  - liamtest2
```

In my playbook I create terraform configuration files for each of these tenants like this:

```
    - name: Generate a .tf file for each tenant in list
      template:
        src: templates/tenant.tf.j2
        dest: "{{ enviro }}/terraform/{{ item }}.tf"
      with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][enviro]['tenants'] }}"
```

Later in the playbook I use the terraform module to apply my configuration and register the outputs to a variable:

```
    - name: Run terraform
      terraform:
        project_path: "{{ enviro }}/terraform/"
        state: present
      register: tf_result
```

I've prefixed my terraform outputs with the tenant name so that I don't get duplicates. This bit is all working fine and I can I can display these outputs with a debug task, for example *tenant*_domain:

```
    - debug:
        var: tf_result.outputs.{{ item + '_domain' }}.value 
      with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][enviro]['tenants'] }}"
```

Produces this output:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=liamtest1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "liamtest1",
    "tf_result.outputs.liamtest1_domain.value": "liamtest1.mydomain.com"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=liamtest2) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "liamtest2",
    "tf_result.outputs.liamtest2_domain.value": "liamtest2.mydomain.com"
}
```

The bit I can't seem to do is generate another set of files (this time javascript files for mongodb) from another Jinja2 template.

I've tried this:

```
    - name: Generate a .js file for each tenant in list
      vars:
        domain: tf_result.outputs.{{ item + '_domain' }}.value
      template:
        src: templates/tenant.js.j2
        dest: "{{ enviro }}/mongodb/{{ item }}.js"
      with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][enviro]['tenants'] }}"
```

If I reference that in my Jinja2 template using `{{ domain }}` it ends up with just a string e.g. `tf_result.outputs.liamtest1_domain.value` in the first file and `tf_result.outputs.liamtest2_domain.value` in the second file.

I also tried using `lookup` in the Jinja2 template like this:

```
{{ lookup('vars', domain) }}
```

Which gives me:

```
"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: No variable found with this name: tf_result.outputs.liamtest1_domain.value"
```

I've also tried some other variations such as:

```
{{ lookup(hostvars[inventory_hostname], domain) }}
```

I've tried a few other things as well, I'm not sure they're all worth mentioning as none of them worked but for example I tried setting the variable inside the Jinja template instead of at the task level like this for example:

```
{% set domain = lookup('vars', 'tf_result.outputs.' + item + '_domain' %}
```

Comment: Sorry for a so short comment but simply: `domain: tf_result.outputs.{{ item + '_domain' }}.value` => `domain: "{{ tf_result.outputs[item + '_domain'].value }}"`.

Comment: @Zeitounator, thank you! That's exactly what I want. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it answered?

Comment: transformed as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have a syntax problem in your yaml.

```
# Wrong
vars:
  domain: tf_result.outputs.{{ item + '_domain' }}.value
```

This is declaring a var which value is a concatenation of (literally) `"tf_result.outputs."` followed by the value of the current `item` and `"_domain.value"`. What you want is the actual value contained in that full variable. This is the correct syntax:

```
# Correct
vars:
  domain: "{{ tf_result.outputs[item + '_domain'].value }}"
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help